# How is the tablecloth getting covered in blood in LXG?

Tags: comics, league-of-extraordinary-gentlemen

In the League of Extraordinary Gentlemen, vol 2,

> Hyde kills Griffin, the Invisible Man, and then eats him at the table.

We see the tablecloth get increasingly covered in blood, and Hyde links that to

> Griffen passing away in the library.

I feel like I'm missing something - if the body is in the library, how is it that blood stains the table to the extant it does, and how come it only starts once he passes away?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a stunning bit of [Fridge Logic](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FridgeLogic) I realised that the blood was always there on Hyde's shirt and the tablecloth.  It was only appearing now that Griffen was dead because, as he was the Invisible Man, his blood was also invisible... until his death.  So it follows that that was how Hyde knew that Griffen was now dead.

Comment: The realization came at 11:30pm at night.  What a mental image to go to sleep to... :(